How to better organise Terraform code using Helm provider
I inherited a Terraform codebase from a former development team. The former development team and I have in common .NET and C# experience, so not really experts.
The current codebase uses Helm provider to deploy charts via helm_release objects defined in modules. The Helm provider is configured via the outputs of an AKS cluster.
Taking into account what Terraform says, modules are a way to reuse resources and should not create only a single resource. Unfortunately the modules being used are not really "reusable" per-se as modules should, because the modules are only a series of helm_resource objects that will be called only once. So, I am trying to review and refactor this mess.
This is an example of my main.tf file:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>3.81.0"
    }
    helm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/helm"
      version = "~>2.4.1"
    }
  }
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = module.aks_cluster.kube_admin_config[0].host
    client_certificate     = base64decode(module.aks_cluster.kube_admin_config[0].client_certificate)
    client_key             = base64decode(module.aks_cluster.kube_admin_config[0].client_key)
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.aks_cluster.kube_admin_config[0].cluster_ca_certificate)
  }
alias = "test"
}

module "cert_manager" {
  source            = "./modules/cert_manager"
  providers = {
    helm = helm.test
  }
}

module "telemetry" {
  source                                      = "./modules/telemetry"

  # Depends_on is needed here because a certificate manager resource must be created first.
  depends_on = [
    module.cert_manager
  ]

  providers = {
    helm = helm.test
  }
}

My objective would be to have all Helm releases properly organised in a directory hierarchy and the provider configuration moved at the root of this directory hierarchy.
The reason is to use Terragrunt in the future, organising the code even better in terms of configuration for different environments.
I thought of creating a folder defining the Helm provider there and creating subfolders with their helm release resources there, eliminating the need of modules:
src
--terraform
---main.tf
--cluster_helm_releases
---main.tf
---cert_manager
----main.tf

content of src/terraform/cluster_helm_releases/main.tf:
provider "helm" {
      kubernetes {
        host                   = module.aks_cluster.kube_admin_config[0].host
        client_certificate     = base64decode(module.aks_cluster.kube_admin_config[0].client_certificate)
        client_key             = base64decode(module.aks_cluster.kube_admin_config[0].client_key)
        cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.aks_cluster.kube_admin_config[0].cluster_ca_certificate)
      }
    alias = "test"
    }

Is this possible? Is it something you would do?
Maybe I should also rethink whether Terraform is the optimal tool to deploy charts in AKS.
What do you suggest?
